# Drawing Custom Drawable Shapes in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-drawable, shapedrawable

Hi Guys I'm new in android development and i want to create a custom shape like the one shown in the below image. I want to know if this can be achieved using xml markup or what is the right way to do it?

[image: Android Drawable]

Comment: This would have to be done programmatically by [creating a custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

Comment: is it done or not?